# Magento 2.3.4 Paypal Plus Blank Page and error 500

Tags: magento2.3.4, onestepcheckout, paypal-plus

I would have the problem with `Paypal Plus` Module for `Magento 2.3.4` from `i-ways`

> https://github.com/i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus

I have a fresh Shop installed on Magento 2.3.4 with `Codazone Fastest` Template and `Fire Checkout`. In my shop is only one Product for testing.

I have installed this module from GitHub for Paypal Plus with composer without any problem or error. In Back End also everything looks good, I set all the parameters for the module (Paypal API and so on).

On the Fron End side, this module is active and user can place an order and is redirected to Paypal log in after login confirms the order on Paypal and is redirected to the Shop. But when is redirected to Shop get a blank page with no errors and the money is debited from his Paypal account. In Magento Back End no new order has been received.

On Server logs he shows me the following **errors**:

1. GET /paypalplus/order/create/?paymentId=PAYID-L4G2SOQ0UU552582T601305K&token=EC-88394458G6941023B&PayerID=7892GT7GLC5EC HTTP/1.0 (with ERROR 500)
2. AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentExtensionInterface in /var/www/vhosts/website_exaple_link/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/website_exaple_link/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Sales\\A...', Array)\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/website_exaple_link/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Sales\\A...')\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/website_exaple_link/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Sales\\A...')\n#3 /var/www/vhosts/website_exaple_link/vendor/magento/framework/O...', referer: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?flow=1-P&ulReturn=true&country=DE&useraction=commit&token=EC-88394458G6941023B&country.x=DE&locale.x=de_DE&nxlr=true

Has anyone else faced this problem and could help us? What do these errors really mean? and how we could make it work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! They made a mistake in file vendor/iways/module-pay-pal-plus/Plugin/Sales/Model/Order/PaymentPlugin.php

Just replace:

OrderPaymentExtensionFactory and OrderPaymentExtensionInterface

With:

OrderPaymentExtensionInterfaceFactory

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed in version 1.3.3 of the PayPalPlus module, see https://github.com/i-ways/magento2-paypal-plus

Like @Hack said, there was an issue with declaration of `OrderPaymentExtensionInterface`

Just upgrade with `composer require iways/module-pay-pal-plus:^1.3.3`